# CCleaner & TaskManager & Registry Editor disappear

Tags: windows-registry, anti-virus, task-manager, ccleaner, eset

A month ago I installed ESET Smart Security with a trial version for a month. After this month has ended, I **uninstalled** it (with its own uninstaller) and installed instead AVG Internet Security. Everything was working fine until the installation of ESET, since then I cannot open my Task Manager. It appears for a second, then disappears. Sometimes it doesn't even appear.

Today I tried to install CCleaner Professional (Trial version), the installation went smooth, but again, when starting it, it disappears in a second. I suppose these mysterious disappearances have to do with the initial ESET. 
Also, when trying to manually clean my registry (*Run-> regedit*), nothing appears. I use Windows 7. How could this be solved?

Comment: Its possible your applications may be blocked by ESET personal firewall.You can add the application in ESET personal firewall setting.

Comment: The problem is that by the time these applications started to disappear, my ESET was already uninstalled.

Comment: Do you have AVG still installed? Could you try to uninstall it to check whether it will help?

Comment: No, it didn't help. Reinstalling Windows helped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check you blacklist. Antivirus software just likes to put almost every third-party applications there.